# Curl system cannot find path

Tags: node.js, curl

I'm trying to install Reaction following this steps https://reactioncommerce.com/docs/master/installation

But I can't get through the first step. Got all installed but when type:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
```

The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Do you have `curl` installed?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I would get curl not recognized?

Comment: Could you please post the error message you are getting?

Comment: the error message is "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: I came here looking for an answer to the same question. In my case, it turned out that @Mr. Llama was on the right track. Yes, @Grasper, you may curl installed, but in the wrong directory. What worked for me was, `full_path_to_curl https://install.meteor.com`

Answer (score 1):

use double quotes (")
curl "https://install.meteor.com" | /bin/sh